# when should I remove/register the 'read operation' in java nio selector?

Tags: java, nio

in my understanding,'read operation' is always being registered.At some places, i find the fact that 'read operation' could be removed

Answer (score 2):

When you don't want to be notified when there's data ready to read.

For various setups you always want to process any bytes available to read as soon as possible, in which case, you register that you're interested in the read event and never remove it.

However, there are various protocols where you want to stop being notified. Primarily, when you **cannot** actually process the bytes; if you keep that registered, you'll keep being 'woken up' continually, which is not what you want.

For example:

- You are sending the read data on to something else, and that 'something else' is currently not ready to receive more, for example, its buffers are full (if it's also a NIO based thing, it not ready for writing right now). In this case you can't keep 'reading', as you have no place to put what you read.
- You are currently writing some data out and the protocol you've set up isn't designed to be interruptible like this - you want to finish sending the message before receiving a new message in return. However, you haven't written it all out yet (for example, because there's plenty to send, you haven't sent it all yet, and the channel is not currently ready for writing).